# Liferay $serviceLocator.findService("com.test.Foo") in portal_normal.vm giving NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I'm using liferay6 and trying to access com.test.Foo (added to ext-service) in portal_normal.vm using

```
#set ($mySvc = $serviceLocator.findService("com.test.Foo"))
```

I'm getting the following exception.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.test.Foo' is defined.

Where do i need to declare this bean?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following snippet

```
$serviceLocator.findService("custom-portlet", "com.test.foo")
```

Replace custom-portlet with your portlet name